# Linear inverter

Tags: inverter, linear

I need for my project a circuit that inverts a signal linearly. For example, if my Vdd=1 and Vin=0.8 then I would like Vout to be 1-0.8=0.2. What is the name of a circuit like this?

Comment: An opamp can do this, but to supply voltage must be more than Vdd.

Comment: Just to clarify your question. The use of the term "inverter" in this context is not standard usage. Normal circumstances an inverter that accepted a 0.8V input would output a -0.8V level. Your question suggests that you are really looking for a "translator", "subtractor" or a "offsetter".

Comment: You should also be stating at least two data points to specify the input to output relationship for linear translation. With just one point with circuit behavior at 0.8V => 0.2V other data points could be a whole range of possibilities. Please specify additional data points.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a universally accepted name for such a circuit, but here is an simple example that will operate from 5V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA2ddq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

The op-amps are assumed to be rail-to-rail input and output.

Here:

R1 = R2

R4/R3 = R6/R5 = 3  (so 25% of the input voltage appears across R1 and R2), with a gain of 0.25 in the input divider and 4 in the output amplifier.

So with 5V input there will be 1.25V across R1 and R2, 3.75V of available Vgs and 2.5V Vds.